# how xmlwriter use with objective c?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uibutton, uitextfield

I want to create xml file. I have three text fields and one button in my interface builder. In three text fields getting value from user. In this code i want to define event on button that is when click on button then all in formation of all three text fields save in xml file. Now i want to write/save these values in xml  file in which i have define  attributes like name of person , email and phone number. I have no idea about xml file so tell how i do that? For that what i will do in xml file? How set code for these event in xcode?

Comment: I am beginners in iPhone coding. So tell step by step how do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly u learn how to use xml in objective C.

and use Tbxml

**http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html**

download the tbxml.Zip and learn this project ...and implement